# Use variables to simplify mod_rewrite rules in .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have inherited a .htaccess file with an extremely complex set of mod_rewrite rules, there are about 100 lines with a lot of duplication much like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(test|dev|((current|archive|all|2x|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27)/([a-z]{2}|pt_br)))/favicon.ico
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(test|dev|((current|archive|all|2x|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27)/([a-z]{2}|pt_br)))/robots.txt
RewriteRule ^(test|dev|((current|archive|all|2x|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27)/([a-z]{2}|pt_br)))/(.*) /index.php?title=$5 [L,QSA,S=1]
```

(Note that the rules do have slight differences and aren't all the same, but there are  constituent parts are consistent between them.)

I would like to use variables to make these rules more maintainable, is this possible? Something a long the lines of this pseudo-example:

```
# define variables
versions=(current|archive|all|2x|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27)
languages=(current|archive|all|2x|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27)
# body of rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(test|dev|($versions/$languages))/favicon.ico
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(test|dev|($versions/$languages))/robots.txt
RewriteRule ^(test|dev|($versions/$languages)/(.*) /index.php?title=$5 [L,QSA,S=1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you cannot store partial regex in variables like this.

As a workaround you can set env variables if these conditions are true:

```
RewriteRule (current|archive|all|2x|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27) - [E=VERSION:$1]

RewriteRule (current|archive|all|2x|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27) - [E=LANG:$1]
```

Once that is done you can use these environment variables in your rules like this in your conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:VERSION} .+
```

OR

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:LANG} .+
```